# iOS - AdHoc Build Confirmation

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, ad-hoc-distribution

I am using XCode 6 and building the IPA. I have been following many posts in Stackoverflow and have gather information and the steps as to how to create the provisioning profiles and build the IPA.

I have been able to build the AdHoc IPA and have been successful in deploying it in my device. The application gets launched and is running fine. Now my query is that, as I am able to install the application on my device without any issues, does it mean that the IPA when uploaded to Apple will also get approved. (I am not using any private APIs. I am building my application using Appcelerator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean that at all.

You've proven only the following:

1. That you have an app that compiles.
2. That you have an appropriate provisioning profile to load to your device.

Apple cares about a lot more than just that. For instance, you say it's "running fine", but Apple will test it fairly thoroughly to see if they can get it to crash. From personal experience, they might even find a crash that you can't replicate on your end (which is ***terribly*** frustrating!).

Also, Apple has gotten more picky about their approval process. I submitted an app that had an **extra** feature that linked to another app that was related but distinct. Apple ruled that my app was incomplete as it required another app to be fully-functional. What did I do? I **removed** the extra feature, and then Apple approved the app. Yes, I took away a feature and my app went from "incomplete" to "complete". My point? Apple's review process is fairly subjective and it can depend on who looks at your app and what kind of day they're having.

On your first app submission, be prepared for several back-and-forth sessions where they reject your app and you have something to fix. On the plus side, they're generally pretty specific about the problem they found, so it makes it easier to fix it!

You may get approved the first time out, but it's a higher bar you have to pass than just the items you mentioned in your post.

## EDIT

Also, you need to make sure that you have an appropriate **Distribution** profile. For loading to your device, you are most likely using a **Development** profile. Make sure you've gone through the steps to create an **App Store** Distribution Profile (which also required a Distribution Certificate, by the way).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and also sharing your experience which means a lot.

But like I mentioned, I am using the AdHoc Distribution profile and no the development profile. The profile is displayed as iOS Distribution in the profile section of developer.apple.com.

Hope that the approval goes smooth once we apply in App Store for approval, touch wood.

Comment: @SoumyaKantiKar Happy to help! Getting an app approved for the App Store can be a long and frustrating process. I know it has been for me a couple of times. Just keep going and checking off items that need to be done and you'll get there eventually! If this answer really helped, you can accept it.

Comment: Just one last query. Once I sign my application with the App Store Distribution profile, apart from using the security cms command to validate it, is there any other way to validate that I have signed the IPA with the proper profile and that it will be acceptable by iTunes. Also while uploading the IPA, will the Application Loader also validate it?

The reason for asking this is because I want to be sure that I am proceeding in the right direction. Till now I have been successful with Dist AdHoc profile. So if I build the application & sign with App Store distribution will that suffice or not.

Comment: I use Xcode to Archive and Export my apps, so I'm not familiar with the "security cms command to validate it". That said, yes, Application Loader will check the file and make sure everything matches up. If you actually get it uploaded to Apple, then you've done everything right from a signature perspective.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted to check. If it gets uploaded to Apple then from signature perspective everything should be fine.

Comment: Correct. <15 characters>

Comment: After building the application with App Store distribution profile, will I be able to deploy it in my test device (in which I have the AdHoc profile installed)?